# Is it Neccessary to Dispose the MvxSubscription token, even if am disposing the Viewmodel in Android OnDestroy method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it Necessary to Dispose the MvxSubscription token, even if am disposing the View model in Android On Destroy method. I have a Home View which is an Activity there are two fragments Home frag and Map frag associated with same View model Homeviewmodel So when I navigate to Map frag from HomeView and comeback to homeview Viewmodel gets destroyed and token also the code to destroy token

```
    public override void DisposeImpl()  
 {           
   _imageClickedToken.Dispose();             
   _commentPostToken.Dispose();           
   _filterArticleToken.Dispose();              
   base.DisposeImpl();  

 }
```

But again the messages doesn't get subscribed

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, No.

As you can see below or at the [mvvmcross](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/messenger) site - you need to hold onto a reference, but you do not need to call dispose. The GC will dispose of the object when it goes out of scope - such as when the ViewModel is disposed in your example.

> Subscriptions can be cancelled at any time using the Unsubscribe
>   method on the IMvxMessenger or by calling Dispose() on the
>   subscription token.
>
> However, in many cases, Unsubscribe/Dispose is never called. Instead
>   listeners rely on the WeakReference implementation of the
>   MvxSubscriptionToken to clear up the subscription when objects go out
>   of scope and Garbage Collection occurs.
>
> This GC-based unsubscription will occur whenever the subscription
>   token returned from Subscribe is Garbage Collected - so if the token
>   is not stored, then A